How to install pytables without blosc2 in termux?
I tried to install pytables in termux (in order to use it in pandas). And I already install the required libs first:
pkg install libhdf5 liblzo bzip2 libblosc

Then I try to install tables via:
LDFLAGS="-lpython3.11" HDF5_DIR=$PREFIX LZO_DIR=$PREFIX BZIP2_DIR=$PREFIX BLOSC_DIR=$PREFIX pip install tables 

With the following error:
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/blosc2_list_compressors_bfwevgv.c:1:10: fatal error: 'blosc2.h' file not found
          1 | #include "blosc2.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      cpuinfo failed, assuming no CPU features: No module named 'cpuinfo'
      * Using Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb 11 2024, 13:05:24) [Clang 17.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project d9f89f4d1
      * Found cython 3.0.10
      * USE_PKGCONFIG: True
      * pkg-config header dirs for HDF5: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include
      * pkg-config library dirs for HDF5: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      * Found HDF5 headers at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include``, library at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib``.
      * Found LZO 2 headers at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include``, library at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib``.
      * Skipping detection of LZO 1 since LZO 2 has already been found.
      * Found bzip2 headers at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include``, library at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib``.
      * pkg-config header dirs for blosc: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include
      * pkg-config library dirs for blosc: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
      * Found blosc headers at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include``, library at ``/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib``.
      * Run 'blosc2_find_directories_hook'
      * Unable to find blosc2 wheel.
      .. ERROR:: Could not find a local blosc2 installation.
         You may need to explicitly state where your local blosc2 headers
         and library can be found by setting the ``BLOSC2_DIR`` environment
         variable or by using the ``--blosc2`` command-line option.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

How can I install tables package without blosc2 installed?
